# Prove $\forall c \in \mathbb{N} \, \exists x,y \in \Sigma^* \, [K(xy) > K(x) + K(y) + c]$

Tags: information-theory, kolmogorov-complexity

I am trying to prove a theorem (title) given in a starred problem in Sipser's book. I have absolutely no idea how I would go about showing it, and after trying a few different approaches came here looking for a hint. I don't want a full answer, but would really appreciate a few words to point me in the right direction. This is not a homework exercise.

Comment: Starred exercises are not supposed to be easy. Keep thinking.

Answer (score 1):

A [paper of Day](http://cjtcs.cs.uchicago.edu/articles/CATS2009/1/cats9-1-1.pdf) gives the following hint: Show that for every $c$, *every* long enough string $z$ contains a prefix $x$ with $K(x) < |x| - c$.

He also gives a hint to the hint: Use the fact that a machine for computing $x$ can use both the given program $\pi$ and its length $|\pi|$, which gives it an extra $\log|\pi|$ bits of information.

Comment: I think I see how the hint makes the problem trivial: take $z=xy$ to be a sufficiently long incompressible string. Then $K(z) = |z| = |x| + |y|$. But $K(x) + K(y) + c_1 < |x| + K(y) < |x| + |y| + c_2 = |z| + c_2$ for any $c_1$ and some $c_2$.  So $K(x) + K(y) + (c_1 - c_2) < |z|$. Since this holds for all $c_1$, I can get $(c_1 - c_2) = c$ for any $c$, QED. Is this correct?

Comment: Also, I saw on your profile you're at the IAS. Do you personally know Martin-Löf?

Comment: Actually I guess in the above I should've said $K(z) \geq |z|$, but that doesn't affect the validity of the argument.

Comment: Actually I am no longer at the IAS. Martin–Löf resides in Stockholm, but I didn't see him when I visited there.